# How to generate array of days and pipe to rest of function

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting to generate a list of weekdays, list which days are Friday, and which Fridays are the last of ones of the month.

So far I have:

```
$days = @()
for($i=0;$i -le 50;$i++){$days += (Get-Date).AddDays($i)}
$days | 
where {$_.DayOfWeek -notlike 'Sunday' -and $_.DayOfWeek -notlike 'Saturday'} | 
foreach{
  if($_.DayOfWeek -like 'Friday'){
    if($_.Month -like $_.AddDays(7).Month){
      Write-Host "$_ - Fri - Not end of month"
    }
    else{
      Write-Host "$_ - Fri - End of month"
    }
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$_ - Mon - Thur"
  }
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if I could pipe it further so that I don't have to declare a `$days` variable.

Something along the lines of:

```
for($i=0;$i -le 50;$i++){(Get-Date).AddDays($i)} | where {$_.DayOfWeek...
```

This does not work since you can't pipe from a for statement.

Is what I'm asking possible? What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe from a for loop by wrapping it in a sub-expression:

```
$(for($i=0;$i -le 50;$i++){(Get-Date).AddDays($i)}) | where {$_.DayOfWeek...
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an accepted solution, and mjolinor does solid work so I'm sure that answer is awesome, I just want to offer an alternative.

You can move the Where clause to inside of your For loop like:

```
for($i=0;$i -le 50;$i++){(Get-Date).AddDays($i) | where {$_.DayOfWeek...}}
```

As an extension of that you can put whatever you want in that For loop that pertains to the date. Also, your If/If/Else clause could probably be better managed with a Switch loop (at least in my opinion). To show both of these points consider this code:

```
for($i=0;$i -le 50;$i++){
    (Get-Date).AddDays($i)|where {$_.DayOfWeek -notlike 'Sunday' -and $_.DayOfWeek -notlike 'Saturday'} | foreach{
        Switch($_){
            {($_.DayOfWeek -like 'Friday') -and ($_.Month -like $_.AddDays(7).Month)}{Write-Host "$($_.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) - Fri: Not end of month";Continue}
            {($_.DayOfWeek -like 'Friday') -and !($_.Month -like $_.AddDays(7).Month)}{Write-Host "$($_.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) - Fri: End of month";Continue}
            Default{Write-Host "$($_.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) - Mon-Thur ($($_.DayOfWeek))"}
        }
    }
}
```

That can be made 1 line if you really want, but it gets a lot harder to read (just like the If/If/Else clauses could be 1 line they're just hard to read if you do). That will output something like the following (only 15 lines shown for brevity):

```
06/09/2014 - Mon-Thur (Monday)
06/10/2014 - Mon-Thur (Tuesday)
06/11/2014 - Mon-Thur (Wednesday)
06/12/2014 - Mon-Thur (Thursday)
06/13/2014 - Fri: Not end of month
06/16/2014 - Mon-Thur (Monday)
06/17/2014 - Mon-Thur (Tuesday)
06/18/2014 - Mon-Thur (Wednesday)
06/19/2014 - Mon-Thur (Thursday)
06/20/2014 - Fri: Not end of month
06/23/2014 - Mon-Thur (Monday)
06/24/2014 - Mon-Thur (Tuesday)
06/25/2014 - Mon-Thur (Wednesday)
06/26/2014 - Mon-Thur (Thursday)
06/27/2014 - Fri: End of month
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I like the switch structure much better! I'm not going to have the script as one line. When I tried to make it one line and couldn't, I needed to know how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I posted that just to show him that a for loop could indeed be made to work with the pipeline.

That DayOfWeek is an enum, and as such has both string and int values.  This is much easier if you use the int values:

```
foreach ($i in 1..50)
 {
   $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays($i)
   $DOW =  [int]$Date.DayOfWeek

   if ($DOW -eq 5) {$Friday = 'Friday!!!' }

   if ($Friday -and ($Date.Month -lt $Date.AddDays(7).Month))
     { $EOM = '- End of month' }

   if ($DOW -match '[1-5]')
     {
       '{0} {1} {2}' -f $Date.ToShortDateString(),$Friday,$EOM
       $Friday,$EOM = $null
     }
  }
```

Comment: Don't  get me wrong, I wasn't trying to one-up you, your first answer was short, sweet, and exactly what he asked for. I was just offering an alternative, and was pimping `Switch` because I think it's under used and neat.

Comment: No offense.  I didn't really look at the details much until you posted another solution (that's my upvote). I just wanted to show how to leverage the int vales of the enum.